# SED - Create new line if finds ONE or ANOTHER MATCH

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I have some files in a folder

Each file has this structure:

```
...
infos: '{"NAME":"Product","CLASSES":[255,107,255,108,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255],"ISSALE":0,"CATEG":54}'
warehouse: 123
color: black
...
```

I need to accomplish bellow scenario **using single SED command**, in all files using *.txt

I need to create a new line ONLY if one of two conditions happens.
If matches 2 conditions it must be generated just ONE line

Conditions:

infos: {...xxxx...."CATEG":54}
OR
warehouse: 123

PS: I dont have the line number, because line number may change file to file.
PS2: I dont know position of CATEG inside {} because "CLASSES" may change size by file
Bellow the scenarios

Match CATEG - 1 line created

```
...
infos: '{"NAME":"Product","CLASSES":[255,107,255,108,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255],"ISSALE":0,"CATEG":54}'
warehouse: 000
NEW LINE
color: black
...
```

Match warehouse - 1 line created

```
...
infos: '{"NAME":"Product","CLASSES":[255,107,255,108,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255],"ISSALE":0,"CATEG":00}'
warehouse: 123
NEW LINE
color: black
...
```

Match CATEG and warehouse - 1 line created

```
...
infos: '{"NAME":"Product","CLASSES":[255,107,255,108,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255],"ISSALE":0,"CATEG":54}'
warehouse: 123
NEW LINE
color: black
...
```

DONT MATCH - No line created

```
...
infos: '{"NAME":"Product","CLASSES":[255,107,255,108,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255],"ISSALE":0,"CATEG":00}'
warehouse: 000
color: black
...
```

Comment: Um, parsing JSON with `sed` is a terrible idea, and honestly, you show no attempt at solving at all … please be a bit more helpful here and describe what you've tried, what your actual constraints are (why would you need to solve something this complex only with sed? That makes no sense!); what is your system? Why is the question tagged with [tag:macos] and [tag:linux] at the same time, and with [tag:bash], which is a non-standard shell under one of these?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Edited tags. About JSON, i use SED with JSON with no problems. Im getting success Matching just one condition. When apply | to accomplish (aORb) (a|b). Nothing happens.

Comment: Regarding "I need to accomplish bellow scenario **using single SED command**" - so if the problem can be solved with 1 or 2 small, simple, portable non-sed commands instead of 1 complicated, lengthy and/or non-portable sed command that's no use to you, right?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you know that `sed` doesn't understand the structure of a `json` data. All it knows are line breaks and strings and regexes to select &/or modify them.

Hence it is very easy to go wrong and what's worse you won't even come to know of it bcoz sed will gladly make changes, until much later downstream.

With the caveats aside, you may attempt to approach this problem using `POSIX`*ly* `sed` :

```bsh
sed -e '

  $!N

  /^infos:.*\nwarehouse:/! {
    P
    D
  }

  /"CATEG":[1-9]/! {
    /\nwarehouse: *[1-9]/! b
  }

  G

' file
```

---

Also if you have`GNU sed` installed (most likely named `gsed`), it can be optimized using the OR `|` operator:

```bsh
sed -E '$!N
  /^infos:|\nwarehouse:/!{P;D;}
  /("CATEG":|^warehouse:\s*)[1-9]/MG
' file
```

---

**Assumptions:**

- infos line and warehouse lines are adjacent.
- the CATEG key is on the infos Key line.

Comment: Every modern `sed` implementation supports extended regular expressions, but with the `-E` option instead of `-r`. Even GNU `sed` switched to support `-E`. But `\s` is a GNU extension.

Comment: @Philippos fixed the extended regex option  now.Thanks.